# Varieties strict inclusion infinitely long

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

Let $F$ be a field, and consider the affine space $F^n$. Could there be affine varieties $V_1,V_2,\ldots\subseteq F^n$ such that $V_1\supset V_2\supset\cdots$, and no two are equal?

Comment: Do you mean closed subvarieties? Then no, because the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{A}^n$ is $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no infinite strictly decreasing sequence of closed subsets of $F^n$ because there is no strictly increasing sequence of ideals in the polynomial ring $F[T_1,...,T_n]$.
Indeed, that ring is noetherian by Hilbert's celebrated [*basis theorem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_basis_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

You can create arbitrarily long chains: in $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ with coordinate ring $k[x]$, where $k$ is a field of characteristic $0$ (in particular infinite), $D(f)$ is an open affine subvariety for any $f \in k[x]$, and there is a chain of strict inclusions $D(x) \supset D(x(x-1)) \supset D(x(x-1)(x-2)) \supset \ldots$

Comment: I think this is wrong, you have the inclusion the incorrect way.

Comment: @Kunal: The inclusions are going the correct way. Double check this carefully, and recall that $V(IJ) = V(I) \cup V(J)$ for any ideals $I, J$.

Comment: Hmm it's $\{0\}, \{0,1\},\{0,1,2\}, \ldots$. Moreover, this answer would contradict Georges Elencwajg's answer.

Comment: No. $D(x) = \mathbb{A}^1_k \setminus V(x)$ is the complement of $\{0\}$, $D(x(x-1))$ is the complement of $\{0,1\}$, and so forth. This does not contradict Georges' answer, as these are *open* subsets

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for my ignorance here. How is a "closed"/"open" subset of $F^n$ defined? It's not the same as a closed subset of a metric space, is it?

Comment: Closedness in algebraic geometry (almost) always refers to the Zariski topology: a set is closed (in the classical setting) if it is the zero locus of a set of polynomials